# Error selecting radio button with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this problem, I got these radio buttons

```
<input type="radio" name="bank" id="bank-1" data-movt="0"> Bank 1 <br />
<input type="radio" name="bank" id="bank-2" data-movt="0"> Bank 2 <br />
```

And when I press my "Save" button it is suppose to get the name of the `id` and the value of `data-movt`, but instead of that always gets the value of the first `radio` button

```
<button type="button" id="save-bank" class="btn-save">Save</button>
```

When I select the second radio button always display my error message, this is my jQuery code:

```
$('#save-bank').click(function() {

    if ($('[name="bank"]').prop('checked') == true) {

        var id   = $('[name="bank"]').attr('id');
        var movt = $('[name="bank"]').data('movt');

        alert(id + ' - ' + movt);

    } else {

        alert('You need to select a bank');
    }
});
```

Am I doing something wrong? missing something? because it only works with the first radio button, I only can choose one radio button, but I need to get the values of the selected radio, I hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: `$(selector).prop('checked')` will always check for `checked` property on the first element matching selector. Use `:checked` selector to select the checked radio button. `$('[name="bank"]:checked')`. [Here is updated code with small improvement](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/9dgx56jL/)

Comment: @Tushar thanks for your answer but I tried your code and it is not working, in both cases it display the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ... this should provide the single element, rather than all the `[name="bank"]` elements.

```
    if ($('[name="bank"]:checked')) {
      var id   = $('[name="bank"]:checked').attr('id');
      var movt = $('[name="bank"]:checked').data('movt');
      alert(id + ' - ' + movt);
    } else {
      alert('You need to select a bank');
    }
```

While you could loop through all the elements, this is a simpler way to select the correct "single" element without the overhead of JavaScript looping.

Comment: Now when I select the second radio is not showing the error message but is displaying the same info that has the first radio button

Comment: Please double check the code; I noticed a mistake in the second and third lines of code, forgot the `:checked` which narrows down the selection when getting the values ... you may have gotten code from before I made this fix.

Comment: Awesome; sorry about missing that.  Lots of turkey today, getting sleepy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check each of the radio button to see if its checked. Once your check that the radio button is checked, your are using the selector as `$('[name="bank"]')` to get the `attr` will will give you the `attr` of the first object found with that selector.

```js
$(function(){
  $('#save-bank').click(function() {
      var count = 0;
      $('[name="bank"]').each(function(){
      
         if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
          
          var id   = $(this).attr('id');
          var movt = $(this).data('movt');

          alert(id + ' - ' + movt);

        } else{
           count++;
        }
      })
      if(count == 2) {
        alert('Select a radio button');
      }
     
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="bank" id="bank-1" data-movt="0"> Bank 1 <br />
<input type="radio" name="bank" id="bank-2" data-movt="0"> Bank 2 <br />
<button type="button" id="save-bank" class="btn-save">Save</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the problem is solved with the answer of @rfornal

Comment: No problem, This is also a way you can achieve the same thing, although @rfornal code is shorter